# Why MySQL multiple-column index is overpopulated?

Tags: mysql, indexing, multiple-columns

Consider following MySQL table:

```
CREATE TABLE `log`
(
    `what` enum('add', 'edit', 'remove') CHARACTER SET ascii COLLATE ascii_bin NOT NULL,
    `with` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,

    KEY `with_what` (`with`,`what`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

INSERT INTO `log` (`what`, `with`) VALUES
    ('add', 1),
    ('edit', 1),
    ('add', 2),
    ('remove', 2);
```

As I understand, `with_what` index must have 2 unique entries on its first `with` level and 3 (EDIT: 4) unique entries in `what` "subindex". But MySQL reports 4 unique entries for each level. In other words, number of unique elements for each level is always equal to number of rows in `log` table.

EDIT: It is okay for the "second level" to have number of unique entries equal to total number of records, but not okay for top level.

EDIT2: Have noticed if number of a bits occupied by `with` column changed, for instance to int(11) and back to int(10), then cardinality start working as expected. Even `EXPLAIN SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT 'with') FROM log` display adequate value for `rows`.

Is that a bug, a feature or my misunderstanding?

Comment: Are your other tables in InnoDB as well? Do they have primary keys? InnoDB will try to make keys unique by appending the primary key to the non-unique keys if I remember it right.

Comment: @Danosaure: Yes, all tables stored using InnoDB. `log` table do not have primary key, other tables do. Strange thing is that other multi-column indexes do not have such problem, even on `log` table. Maybe there is some bug or something. I worried about this so much because `log` table is the fastest growing table in the project. It may wast too much time and space building that large inefficient index.

Comment: What do you mean by "MySQL reports 4 unique entries for each level"? Where do you look?

Comment: @Quassnoi: `SHOW INDEXES FROM table_name` or in phpMyAdmin see Structure tab of the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SHOW INDEXES` shows statistics which are approximate.

These statistics are gathered automatically as the queries to the table are performed, and additionally, you can force gathering them manually by issuing `ANALYZE TABLE log`.

The value in the cardinality column is not exact and it can change between calls to `ANALYZE`, even if the underlying table is not changed.

Comment: Is there any way to see exact cardinality? I just wonder why that is the only index with so extremely inaccurate cardinality while others are completely accurate.

Comment: @actual: `SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT column) FROM mytable`

Answer (score 0):

Your understanding is wrong. Multi column key is created from multiple values, not for multiple columns. MySQL reports 4 unique entries because you entered 4 unique pairs of entries.

You have described separate indexes for these columns, so instead

```
KEY `with_what` (`with`,`what`)
```

it should be

```
KEY `with` (`with`),
KEY `what` (`what`)
```

And it should work as you wanted it to.

Comment: If add another entry of ('edit', 1), it will report 5 unique entries. Something is wrong here.

Comment: BTW, I do not need single-column indexes. Other multiple-column indexes in my project behave in the normal way and not overpopulated. For example, I have another `who_when` index and number of its first level unique entries equal to the number of users (`who`), not to the total number of rows in `log` table.

Answer (score 0):

you should think of a "multi column" index as a "concatenated index", meaning the individual columns are concatenated in the index. That is, there is one index entry for each row, and that entry contains all indexed columns.

Have a look at my eBook to get the full picture how indexes work: http://Use-The-Index-Luke.com/